# How can I attach a class to each element separately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list of 4 boxes, each have two sections `.content-primary-wrapper` and `.content-secondary-wrapper`, inside both these sections is a div called `.content-inner`. I am running a conditional based on the heights of the `content-inner` classes to decide which one get's a border-class addd to it.

As I have it now, the function runs, then applies the results to all of the classes, how can I get it to apply it on an element basis? I am trying to get it so it works like this:

1. Run function, determine heights of first element
2. determine heights of first element
3. Apply border class to this element only
4. Rinse and repeat for the other 3 objects

Here is my script I am using, any ideas how I could loop through these?

```
var primary_height = $('.content-primary-wrapper .content-inner').height();

var secondary_height = $('.content-secondary-wrapper .content-inner').height();

if ( primary_height >= secondary_height ){
   $(this).find('.content-primary-wrapper .content-inner').addClass('add-border-right');
} else {
   $(this).find('.content-secondary-wrapper .content-inner').addClass('add-border-left');
}
```

Comment: loop over each one https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're going for? Loop through all of your boxes, find the `.content-inner`s in each one, and apply your class.

```js
$(".box").each(function() {
  var $pri = $(this).find(".content-primary-wrapper .content-inner"),
      $sec = $(this).find(".content-secondary-wrapper .content-inner");
  if ($pri.height() >= $sec.height()) {
    $pri.addClass("add-border-right");
  } else {
    $sec.addClass("add-border-left");
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.add-border-left {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
.add-border-right {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="content-primary-wrapper">
    <div class="content-inner">two<br>lines</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-secondary-wrapper">
    <div class="content-inner">one</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="content-primary-wrapper">
    <div class="content-inner">one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-secondary-wrapper">
    <div class="content-inner">two<br>lines</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was mostly it, had to set the border onto the `content-primary /secondary-wrapper` elements, but besides that, this worked wonders! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could do this. I would probably run a selector to get the elements that contain the four boxes, then run localized queries for the primary and secondary wrappers on them, like so:

```
$('.box-container').each(function(index, container) {
    var primary_height = $('.content-primary-wrapper .content-inner', container).height();
    var secondary_height = $('.content-secondary-wrapper .content-inner', container).height();
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you're sure that they're always going to be paired like this, you could simply do something like:

```
var primary_elements = $('.content-primary-wrapper .content-inner');
var secondary_elements = $('.content-secondary-wrapper .content-inner');
var i;

for (i = 0; i < primary_elements.length; ++i) {
    var primary_height = $(primary_elements[i]).height();
    var secondary_height = $(secondary_elements[i]).height();
    // ...
}
```

This version seems a little less robust to me, just in case you start removing one or the other element at some point and they're no longer always paired in the way that this assumes.

Comment: I'm working with your for loop solution, but keep running into `Uncaught TypeError: primary_elements[i].height is not a function`, any ideas?

Comment: I believe that the changes I've just made to surround the elements with $() should cover that. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: So now it's firing and creating the border, but it's adding the border to both elements, almost like it starts adding them, then as it iterates and finds one of the opposite, all of those classes receive the border.